# For what values of $m$ and $c$ does the ellipse have focii at $(\pm c,0)$?

Tags: conic-sections

The ellipse equation is:

$$(1+m^2)x^2+y^2 = 1 + 2m^2 + m^4$$

I used Remarkable identities concepts and distributive rule for development but I got stuck. I considered $a = (1+m^2)^2$ and $b=(1+m^2)$.

$$(1+m^2)x^2+y^2 = 1 + 2m^2 + m^4 $$
$$ (1+m^2)x^2+y^2 = (1+m^2)^2 $$
$$ a^2 = b^2 + c^2 $$
$$ (1+m^2)^2 = (1+m^2) + c^2 $$
$$ 1 + 2m^2 + m^4 = 1 + m^2 + c^2 $$
$$ 1 + 2m^2 + m^4 - 1 - m^2 = c^2 $$
$$ m^4 - m^2 = c^2 $$

Any help?

Comment: Hi Jessy, welcome to Math@SE! Please try to use MathJax formatting next time.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that the ellipse is vertical, $b^2=1+m^2$ and $a^2=(1+m^2)^2$ then 
$$c^2=a^2-b^2=m^2(1+m^2)$$